# Pre-commit override arguments in yaml file

Tags: terraform, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I'm using **pre-commit** to validate my terraform projects. My default configs for most of project as below:

```
cat <<EOF > .pre-commit-config.yaml
repos:
- repo: https://github.com/antonbabenko/pre-commit-terraform
  rev: v1.64.0
  hooks:
    - id: terraform_tflint
      args:
        - --args=--var-file=dev.tfvars
        - --args=--var-file=uat.tfvars
        - --args=--var-file=prod.tfvars
```

I rollout this config for all envs. It's working well now. But I have few projects which don't need to have tfvars file for 3 envs. Ex: They only need 1 tfvars in dev. I will get the error with pre-commit.

So I want to input args as variable when I run pre-commit command. Anyone has a solution for this case

Answer (score 1):

**there is intentionally no such option** -- `pre-commit` will only run the configured commands and arguments such that if it is configured in a repository it will be the same for any user with that repository and configuration.  repository-specific configuration (`.pre-commit-config.yaml`) is not intended to be shared across repositories (there is intentionally no mechanism to do so)

you should use the specific arguments in the specific repository's configuration which needs them

---

disclaimer: I created pre-commit

Comment: What if I want to have common pre-commit rules across many projects, but some little things are different? I don't want to copy/paste whole configuration to all projects. And then when you update something, to do same update on all projects. Currently I'm using pre-commit config repository as submodule on specific projects, with files symlinked. So if I update something I can easily update to all repos. Though its problematic, if config must have some differences.

Comment: @Andrius I see you've independently derived exactly why it's intentionally not shared

Comment: Why its intentionally done to not share it? So if I have 100 projects that want to use same configuration, I have to manually do for each project?.. That makes no sense.

Comment: **Though its problematic, if config must have some differences.** <=========

Comment: Well so what do you suggest to do it if it has minimal differences, but most of config is the same? Copy/paste to all projects or use some better technique?